# Change several images position when one of them is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a couple of images, and when I hover over one of them, I want all the images to change position. There should also be an animation when the images change place so they slide to their new position. I am using jQuery. I have been trying different solutions but nothing works, so I don't post any javascript.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="picture one"></div>
    <div class="picture two"></div>
    <div class="picture three"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.picture {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
}

.two {
    left: 60px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.three {
    left: 35px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.three:hover {
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
}

.two:hover {
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}

.one:hover {
    left: 200px;
}
```

Link to jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LJ9wL/2/

Comment: even you will not post your code here explain how they should be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a start. http://jsfiddle.net/LJ9wL/3/

```
$('.picture').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.picture').css({top: '0', left: '200px'});
    $(this).css({top: '60px', left: '20px'});
});

$('.picture').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.picture').css({top: '0', left: '200px'});
    $(this).css({top: '0', left: '200px'});
});
```